# How to modify default options in Salt Minion config file from Master

Tags: salt-stack

I want to set "grains_cache" variable to "True" from Salt Master on all Minions. This variable is from default options that exist in minion config file and cannot be overridden by pillar data. So how can I set variables (for example "grains_cache", "grains_cache_expiration" or "log_file") from Master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be an easy one. Manage the minion configuration file using the `file.managed` [function](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed).
A simple sls should help here:

```
minion_configuration:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/salt/minion
    - contents: |
        grains_cache: true
        backup_mode: minion

salt-minion-restart:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: salt-call --local service.restart salt-minion
    - bg: True
    - order: last
    - watch:
      - file: salt-minion-config
```

In this example, saltstack ensures that the two lines beneath `- contents: |` are present within the minions configuration file.

The second state: `salt-minion-restart` will restart the salt-minion if the minion configuration file is being touched (managed by the first state).
So in short terms, this state adds your variables to the minion's configuration and restarts the minion afterwards.

This formula is os-independent.
The last thing left to do is, to target all of your minions with this.

If you want to know more about the `cmd.wait` and the shown example, please refer to [this documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.wait).

I hope i could help.

Comment: Thanks @PortalMario , but after execution the first segment `minion_configuration`, all the contents of minion config file replaced with `grains_cache: true` and `backup_mode: minion`. Is ther any way to avoid it?

Comment: Minion: "Windows Server 2012"

Comment: @Amir yes, sorry it will override the file. I did not know that you already got some configuration in the file. You can append however the variable, at the end of the file by using file.append! https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.append

Comment: Thansk @PortalMario. We could probably do a file.append on the minion config file if it's something that's not already there. We can use minion.d directory as an alternative solution: [How to modify default options in Salt Minion config file from Master](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/56936)